# Typescript and jQuery: "expected '{'"

Tags: jquery, typescript

I get strange compiling errors when using jquery.d.ts:

```
/var/www/increment_god/jquery.d.ts (165,59): Expected '{'
```

But line 165 only contains this row:

```
interface JQueryXHR extends XMLHttpRequest, JQueryPromise<any> {
```

How to resolve this? I'm using the latest tsc and jquery files. I get similar errors when trying to compile `angular.d.ts` too.

If I remove `<any>` from the line above, the next compilation error will be at `jQueryPromise<T>`.

Comment: It can be some script you're loading before this one that has a missing semicolon or closing bracket.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I only have one file before loading jQuery, and it works fine without `/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />`

Comment: You are probably missing a curly bracket somewhere in your code. You can start by removing js files or looked at the files you wrote

Comment: @Huangism I tested and get this error even if `jquery.d.ts` is the _only_ file I use. Do I use the wrong version of typescript? How do I know? I installed it using npm.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Oh, maybe redownload that file and see if makes a difference. Did you minify it or edit it at all?

Comment: @Huangism I think my installation is $#@!, at `npm i -g typescript` it shows `typescript@0.8.0`, but `npm view typescript version` shows `1.0.1`. I noticed `tsc` lacks a `--version` switch.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt there you go, so if you manage to fix that, it will most likely solve the isue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed old version of node and typescript without knowing. The old typescript does not support generics, thus the errors.